# Save Grafana alert to SQL Database

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-variable

We are using Grafana to monitor security events occurrng by our clients. We have teams that deal with and resolve these events and problems that occur.

We want to have the Grafana alerts automatically turned into service tickets by having the alerts details saved to our Database.

Is there a way to configure Grafana to do this?

Is it possible to build my own Web API to do the work and add it as a custom notification type?

Any other alternatives?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is stated in [Grafana Documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/alerting/notifications/#all-supported-notifier) that one of the Supported Notification Types in Grafana is Webhook.

They say there that

> The webhook notification is a simple way to send information about a state change over HTTP to a custom endpoint. Using this notification you could integrate Grafana into a system of your choosing.

So in the Webhook the message or details from Grafana could be saved to a Data Base table.